# Magento Rest API Error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, laravel, rest, curl, magento

I am accessing Magento rest APIs in my live server and I am getting response code 503 for that, In my localhost that works fine and my Magento site also works fine I have also tried,

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

also if I am accessing APIs in browser it also works fine not getting what is the problem,

its saying **Checking your browser before accessing [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com)** in html response but not getting that error in localhost or postman.

Comment: any luck with that issue?
I am facing it now

Comment: @FahdYousri In my case i was facing that issue because my magento site was cloudflare protected that's why i was facing that issue, when i have added safe url in protection window then error is gone...